# Running Python and PHP on the same server

Tags: nginx, php, python

I've got Django, Gunicorn, and Nginx set up and working nicely together. I'm only going to have a few pages on this Django website, so I'm trying to I'm trying to set up the server such that files ending in `.php` would be interpreted as PHP, and files ending in `.js` would be interpreted as JavaScript for Node.js (that could get a bit tricky, I know). This would be ideal for me so that I do not need to run multiple servers for my testing needs. Rather, I would be able to throw code on the site and just have it work.

As of now, I am only concerned with PHP. I'd like to get that running first. For the Python side of things, I have this in my `nginx.conf`:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

And for the PHP side of things, I have this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

But it doesn't work, and I don't know why. I get a sever error like this when I attempt to access a `/php` directory with a single `index.php` including only a `phpinfo()` call:

> 2015/01/27 12:49:20 [error] 908#0: *3 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/php", host: "mrcsmcln.dev"

Please note that I have edited my `/etc/hosts` file such that `mrcsmcln.dev` maps to `localhost`.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think it were because of an unwanted interaction, maybe you could reformulate your question to not suspecting it. For example, to: "misterius fastcgi connection problem" or some similar.

Comment: `request: "GET /php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/php", host: "mrcsmcln.dev"` why would you expect `/php` to be processed as a php script? It's a folder and does not match `\.php$`, once a request matches a location block all other location blocks are ignored. Since you're using a different host anyway, you could just as easily use a different host for each language or project - which will help eliminate "my dev env is different than production" problems should you ever deploy your local projects.

Comment: @AD7six Like I said in the question, I have an `index.php` file in the directory. I come from Apache, so in my understanding, files like this are processed automatically using `DirectoryIndex`. But I even tried `/php/index.php` and still no dice. As for using different hosts, I think that might be what I do. The idea seems pretty nice to me.